# Change of format for whodunnit between Rails 4.1 and Rails 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, paper-trail-gem

I'm in the process of upgrading our app from Rails 4.1 to Rails 4.2 and I'm running into an issue with the `whodunnit` field.

In Rails 4.1 the `whodunnit` field ends up as a YAML string, while under Rails 4.2, it is a text representation of a hash. I'm using PaperTrail 5.1.1.

## Rails 4.1

```
[1] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::xxx::xx>x)> assigns(:session).versions.last.whodunnit
=> "---\n:admin_id: 5\n"
```

## Rails 4.2

```
[4] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::xxx::xxx>)> assigns(:session).versions.last.whodunnit
=> "{:admin_id=>1}"
```

Does anybody have any idea why this change might have happened and if it's consequential.

Comment: Two questions: Do you define a `user_for_paper_trail` method? Can you show the `create table` definition of your `versions` table?